# Loop crashing/ corrupting after several (perfectly fine) iterations

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop

I'm working on a program for a school project which is designed to output all the card values in a game of blackjack and tell you a few things about some possible combos of those cards.

The loop is designed to drop a card in to the hand and check some different possibilities before dropping another card in and doing the same, when it reaches five cards it clears the hand and moves to a new set of card values until it has used all the cards in the deck.

Right now every fourth and fifth card is somehow becoming broken during the loop. Keep in mind that although I'm working with pointers, arrays, and classes (and more), I still don't fully understand what everything is doing, even having read through the book "C++ Early Objects Eighth edition" up to chapter 10.

Here is an example of the output which occurs, it shows that the score keeper is scoring correctly but the cards being placed in to the hand are starting to mess up in the fifth iteration of the loop which seems to be reflected in the score.

AC 2C 3C 4C 5C 6C 7C 8C 9C TC JC QC KC

AH 2H 3H 4H 5H 6H 7H 8H 9H TH JH QH KH

AD 2D 3D 4D 5D 6D 7D 8D 9D TD JD QD KD

AS 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S 8S 9S TS JS QS KS

AC : AC : 1 : 11 : 0 : 0 : 1 : 1

2C : AC2C : 3 : 13 : 0 : 0 : 2 : 1

3C : AC2C3C : 6 : 16 : 0 : 0 : 3 : 1

4C : AC2C3C4C : 10 : 20 : 0 : 0 : 4 : 1

5C : AC2C3C  AC : 7 : 20 : 0 : 1 : 5 : 0

Clearing hand

6C : 6C : 6 : 6 : 0 : 0 : 1 : 1

7C : 6C7C : 13 : 13 : 0 : 0 : 2 : 1

8C : 6C7C8C : 21 : 21 : 0 : 0 : 3 : 1

9C : 6C7C8C9C : 30 : 30 : 1 : 0 : 4 : 1

TC : 6C7C8C C6C : 27 : 27 : 1 : 1 : 5 : 0

...there are several more here but I took them out because its the same issue over and over...

Clearing hand

QS : QS : 10 : 10 : 0 : 0 : 1 : 1

KS : QSKS : 20 : 20 : 0 : 0 : 2 : 1

...right here it crashes rather than finishing the hand...

and to make this a little more easy to read I'll tell you what each part (separated by colons) represents on one line

((the first/next card is shown)  X:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

(shows whatever is in the hand)  0:X:0:0:0:0:0:0

(the score assuming any aces are ones)  0:0:X:0:0:0:0:0

(the score assuming the first ace in the hand is eleven and all others are one)  0:0:0:X:0:0:0:0

(a bool to represent if the hand is bust)  0:0:0:0:X:0:0:0

(a bool to represent a full hand)  0:0:0:0:0:X:0:0

(The number of cards in the hand)  0:0:0:0:0:0:X:0

(A bool to determine if another card may be drawn)) 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:X

The very top part is just showing all the card values that are possible and seems to work fine. What I'm wondering is why the fifth iteration seems to be having trouble leaving the fourth card alone and not messing up the fifth card, and of course why its crashing. Here is my code,

My main file which has to be right because the teacher gave it to us and we aren't supposed to mess with it:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "BlackJackHand.h"
 #include "PlayingCard.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

  // Create a Blackjack hand object
   BlackJackHand myHand;

  // arrays of values and suits for normal cards
   char
     *values = "A23456789TJQK",
     *suits = "CHDS";

  const int DECK_SIZE = 52;
   const int SUIT_SIZE = 13;
   PlayingCard *deck[DECK_SIZE]; // array of pointers to class objects

  // Initialize and display a card deck
   int
     i,
     j;

  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     for(j = 0; j<SUIT_SIZE; j++) {
       deck[i * SUIT_SIZE + j] = new PlayingCard(values[j], suits[i]);
       cout << deck[i * SUIT_SIZE + j]->getCardCode();
       cout << " ";
     }
     cout << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;

  // Add each from deck to hand, then remove card from hand
   // before adding next card. Check funcs.
   for(i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++) {
     cout << deck[i]->getCardCode();
     myHand.addCard(deck[i]);
     deck[i] = NULL;  // Remove card from deck
     cout << " : ";
     cout << myHand.getAllCardCodes();
     cout << " : " << myHand.getLowScore()
       << " : " << myHand.getHighScore()
       << " : " << myHand.isBust()
       << " : " << myHand.isFull()
       << " : " << myHand.getCardCount()
       << " : " << myHand.canTakeCard()
       << endl;
     if(!myHand.canTakeCard()) {
         cout << "\nClearing hand\n";
         myHand.clearHand();
     }
   } // end for

  cout << "\nClearing hand\n";
   myHand.clearHand();

  PlayingCard
     *card1 = new PlayingCard('J', 'C'),
     *card2 = new PlayingCard('A', 'S'),
     *card3 = new PlayingCard('A', 'D');


  BlackJackHand hand2 = BlackJackHand(card1,card2);
   card1 = card2 = 0;
   cout << hand2.getAllCardCodes();
   cout << " : " << hand2.getLowScore()
     << " : " << hand2.getHighScore()
     << " : " << hand2.isBust()
     << " : " << hand2.isFull()
     << " : " << hand2.getCardCount()
     << " : " << hand2.canTakeCard()
     << endl;

  cout << "\nAdding a second ace:\n";

  hand2.addCard(card3);
   card3 = 0;
   cout <<hand2.getAllCardCodes();
   cout << " : " << hand2.getLowScore()
     << " : " << hand2.getHighScore()
     << " : " << hand2.isBust()
     << " : " << hand2.isFull()
     << " : " << hand2.getCardCount()
     << " : " << hand2.canTakeCard()
     << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
         if (deck[i] != NULL)
             delete deck[i];

  return 0;
 } // end main
```

Heres the class.h for the hand

```
#ifndef BLACKJACKHAND_H
#define BLACKJACKHAND_H
#include <iostream>
#include "PlayingCard.h"

using namespace std;

class BlackJackHand
{
    public:
        BlackJackHand();
//          Default constructor. Initializes private member variables.

        BlackJackHand(class PlayingCard *c1, class PlayingCard *c2);
//          Overloaded constructor.
//          Initializes private member variables and adds c1 and c2 to the hand.
        bool addCard(PlayingCard *card);
//          For adding a card to the hand.
//          It will print a warning, not add the card,
//          and return false if one of these conditions is true:
//          The low score of the hand is 21
//          The hand is bust (low value > 21)
//          The hand is full (the full number of cards has been added to the hand)
//          If the card is successfully added, this function returns true.
        PlayingCard *hand[5];
        int getCardCount();
//          Returns the number of cards that are in the hand.
        int getHighScore();
//          As you probably know, blackjack allows an ace to count as either a 1 or an 11.
//          This function returns the score of the hand counting the first ace in the hand as an 11.
//          Make sure you don't count all the aces as 11.
        int getLowScore();
//          Returns the score counting all the aces as 1.
        void clearHand();
//          This function clears the hand. Any cards in the hand are deleted.
//          Deleted means that the delete operator is used on every card in the hand.
        bool isBust();
//          Returns true if the lowScore is above 21, false if not.
        bool isFull();
//          Returns true if the hand is full, i.e. the hand has 5 cards in it.
        bool canTakeCard();
//          Returns true if the hand can take another card.
//          That means that the low score is less than 21 and the hand has less than 5 cards in it.
        string getAllCardCodes();
//          Displays the cards in the hand. Each card is displayed followed by a space.
    private:
       string *c1,
              *c2;
        int count;
};

#endif // BLACKJACKHAND_H
```

And here is the class.cpp for the hand

```
#include <iostream>
#include "PlayingCard.h"
#include "BlackJackHand.h"


BlackJackHand::BlackJackHand()
{
    hand[0] = 0;
    hand[1] = 0;
    hand[2] = 0;
    hand[3] = 0;
    hand[4] = 0;

    count = 0;
}

BlackJackHand::BlackJackHand(PlayingCard *c1, PlayingCard *c2)
{
    hand[0] = c1;
    hand[1] = c2;
    hand[2] = 0;
    hand[3] = 0;
    hand[4] = 0;

    count += 2;

}
bool BlackJackHand::addCard(PlayingCard *card)
{
    if (getLowScore() < 21 || getLowScore() < 21 || isFull() == false)
    {
        hand[getCardCount()] = card;
        count ++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
int BlackJackHand::getCardCount()
{
    return count;
}
int BlackJackHand::getHighScore()
{
    int scoreHigh = 0;
    bool aceCount = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < getCardCount(); i++)
    {
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "AC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "AS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "AD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "AH")
        {
            if (aceCount == false)
            {
                scoreHigh += 11;
                aceCount = true;
            }
            else
            {
                scoreHigh += 1;
            }
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "2C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "2S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "2D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "2H")
        {
            scoreHigh += 2;
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "3C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "3S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "3D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "3H")
        {
            scoreHigh += 3;
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "4C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "4S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "4D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "4H")
        {
            scoreHigh += 4;
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "5C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "5S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "5D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "5H")
        {
            scoreHigh += 5;
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "6C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "6S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "6D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "6H")
        {
            scoreHigh += 6;
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "7C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "7S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "7D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "7H")
        {
            scoreHigh += 7;
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "8C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "8S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "8D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "8H")
        {
            scoreHigh += 8;
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "9C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "9S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "9D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "9H")
        {
            scoreHigh += 9;
        }
        if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "TC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "TS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "TD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "TH" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "JC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "JS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "JD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "JH" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "QC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "QS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "QD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "QH" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "KC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "KS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "KD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "KH")
        {
            scoreHigh += 10;
        }
        else
        {
            scoreHigh += 0;
        }
    }
    return scoreHigh;
}
int BlackJackHand::getLowScore()
{
        int scoreLow = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getCardCount(); i++)
        {
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "AC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "AS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "AD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "AH")
            {
                scoreLow += 1;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "2C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "2S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "2D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "2H")
            {
                scoreLow += 2;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "3C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "3S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "3D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "3H")
            {
                scoreLow += 3;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "4C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "4S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "4D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "4H")
            {
                scoreLow += 4;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "5C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "5S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "5D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "5H")
            {
                scoreLow += 5;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "6C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "6S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "6D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "6H")
            {
                scoreLow += 6;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "7C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "7S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "7D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "7H")
            {
                scoreLow += 7;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "8C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "8S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "8D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "8H")
            {
                scoreLow += 8;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "9C" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "9S" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "9D" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "9H")
            {
                scoreLow += 9;
            }
            if (hand[i]->getCardCode() == "TC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "TS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "TD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "TH" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "JC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "JS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "JD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "JH" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "QC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "QS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "QD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "QH" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "KC" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "KS" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "KD" || hand[i]->getCardCode() == "KH")
            {
                scoreLow += 10;
            }
            else
            {
                scoreLow += 0;
            }
        }
    return scoreLow;
}
void BlackJackHand::clearHand()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        hand[i] = NULL;
    }
    count = 0;
}
bool BlackJackHand::isBust()
{
    if (getHighScore() > 21)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
bool BlackJackHand::isFull()
{
    if (getCardCount() == 5)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool BlackJackHand::canTakeCard()
{
    if (BlackJackHand::isFull() == false)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
string BlackJackHand::getAllCardCodes()
{
    string allCodes = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < getCardCount(); i++)
    {
        allCodes += hand[i]->getCardCode();
    }
    return allCodes;
}
```

I'm not asking for help with my coding style (or lack there of), just looking to figure out what is wrong in this code. I have two other files for another class which aren't really needed here (but if you ask, I will post them) since they had to be working for a previous project in order for me to move on to this project I think they work fine. Any help will be much appreciated as I am at a dead end and I just don't know how to find answers to this problem since I'm not well versed in the terminology of C++ or programming in general.

Comment: Your code is way too long. Make sure that you don't access out-of-bounds.

Comment: You're going to need to narrow this down first! SO is not a debugging service!

Comment: `if (getLowScore() < 21 || getLowScore() < 21`  Seems you want one of those to be a different function, and with your logic you can add a card to a full hand as long as the total is under 21.  I'd say you're going outside the bounds of the array.  I would also encourage you to use `<` or `>` for comparisons of size, because once you incorrectly add a card to a full hand it won't report as full anymore because of the exact size comparison.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses I will try to narrow it down but it is difficult for me to do that since I don't know exactly what I'm doing. I will try your suggestions Retired Ninja!

Comment: One was meant to be highscore, not sure when I messed that up. I changed the isfull() function to check if its greater than or equal to 5 so it should be a better filter, but it is still crashing in the same place and doing the same iteration wrong

Comment: *"I'm... just looking to figure out what is wrong in this code."* It doesn't work that way. The fundamental problem with this code is that you wrote it the wrong way. It's not your fault, you're a beginner, but the fastest way to get this code working is to build up from the simple to the complex, *not* rush to fix every bug you see and hand in the assignment. We can help, but you must be willing to go step by step.

Comment: I'm sure it's completely obvious but I'll say this anyway. I'm totally new to Stack Overflow and only slightly less new to programming. The class I'm in is the second part of a two part c++ course and it is going at a much higher speed than the first class did. It feels like we went from 5 miles an hour in c++ 1 to trying to match the speed of light in c++ 2.

Comment: I'm very willing to learn everything that you wish to teach me, believe me I need it. My intent is to learn from what I'm doing wrong so that I better understand how to build a program later. There is no true deadline on this assignment as it is already late and our teacher is pretty chill about turning things in. I have no doubt my coding is terrible but it is the best I can do so far. Any advice about posting or anything else on Stack Overflow is appreciated as well since I'm a newborn here.

Comment: Even if you fixed using the low score twice and the hand full function the logic is wrong when you add a card.  The logic you most likely want is `if(!full && (low < 21 || high < 21))`  If you use only or then the deck can be full but one of the scores is low enough so you add a card past the end of the array.  Learning to run your code in a debugger to see where it crashes and to be able to step through the code and see what's happening is a very valuable skill to have.  You might consider that.

Comment: Ok, I'll fix that. And yes I need to learn how to do that with code blocks, I haven't figured out the debugger yet.

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong but that actually made it worse. I did if (isFull() == false && (getHighScore() < 21 || getLowScore() < 21))

Answer (score 1):

All right, this may take a few iterations. Let's see... When I gin up `PlayingCard` and run the code, it doesn't crash. You say it crashes right after:

```
KS : QSKS : 20 : 20 : 0 : 0 : 2 : 1
```

Which should be the end of the deck. In my version, it proceeds to clear the hand and make some new cards. Let's be certain that it's crashing here. (I suspect it isn't.) Add a couple of out lines to your code:

```
} // end for

cout << "deck is empty" << endl;

cout << "\nClearing hand\n";
myHand.clearHand();

cout << "done" << endl;
```

Run that, and tell us what happens (by adding a comment to this answer).

**EDIT:**

(Be careful about reporting the output-- a small mistake can send us down the wrong road.)

Let's cut out most of the code in the main function:

```
int main() {

  // CUT!

  PlayingCard
  *card1 = new PlayingCard('J', 'C'),
  *card2 = new PlayingCard('A', 'S'),
  *card3 = new PlayingCard('A', 'D');

  ...
    << endl;

  // comment these lines out, since the deck no longer exists:
  //  for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
  //    if (deck[i] != NULL)      
  //      delete deck[i];
  return 0;
} // end main
```

Give that a try, and tell us the result.

Comment: I'm not sure where you intended for me to put this code, I can't add it to main because I'm not allowed to alter the main file at all...

Comment: @DiJiT: *Make a copy* of the main file, and monkey with that for purposes of testing. We won't tell.

Comment: I don't know if crashing is the right word here but the program "dies" after that point on my computer.

Comment: @DiJiT: If it doesn't proceed to say "Clearing hand" and start making the {JK, AS, AD} hand, then something is going wrong right around there.

Comment: It's now displaying the correct values in the hand and as a result the scores are correct but it still stops in the same place.

Comment: So it doesn't say "deck is empty"? Then remove the code after the "deck is empty" line and before the "return 0;", run it again to verify that it doesn't say "deck is empty", and then we can attack the main loop...

Comment: I'm sorry, it does say deck is empty, then it says clearing hand then done, then clearing hand then it stops working

Comment: So after trying the last post/edit from @Beta my program now will now pause and say it crashed without cout-ing anything at all...

Comment: Heres my favorite part, without actually changing anything, I took it to school and the program proceeded to run correctly, other than "crashing" at the end, so I brought it back to my house and it now runs the same here...

Comment: @DiJiT: So... do you still want help?

Comment: Just resolved this one today. How do I close this question? Also I will try to bring a more specific problem next time instead of the pages of crappy code that I posted this time. Thank you all for the help you provided.

Comment: this was messing with the end of my program. hand[0] = c1;
    hand[1] = c2;
    hand[2] = 0;
    hand[3] = 0;
    hand[4] = 0;

    **count += 2;**                                                                                           it should have been count = 2;

Comment: How do I close this question?

Comment: @DiJiT: It has four votes for closure already. If it isn't closed soon, I'll flag it for a moderator's attention.